# Work-item execution order

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I am working with OpenCL. And I am interested how work-item will be executed in the following example.

I have one-dimensional range of 10000 with a work-group size of  512. The kernel is the followin:

```
__kernel void
doStreaming() {
  unsigned int id = get_global_id(0);

  if (!isExecutable(id))
    return;

 /* do some work */
}
```

Here it check if it need to proceed the element with the following id or not.

Let assume that the execution started with the first work-group of 512 size and 20 of them were rejected by `isExecutable`. Does GPU continue to execute other 20 elements without waiting the first 492 elements?

There are no any barriers or other synchronization techniques involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When some workitems are branching far from the usual /* do some work */, they can use pipeline occupation advantage by getting instructions from next wavefront(amd) or next warp(nvidia) because current warp/wavefront workitem is busy doing other things. But this can cause memory access serialization and purge the accessing order of workgroup, decreasing performance.

**Avoid having diverged warps/wavefronts**: If you do if-statements in loop, it is really bad so better you find another way.

If every work item in a workgroup is having same branching, then it is ok.

If every work item does very few branching per hundreds of computing, it is ok.

Try to generate equal conditions for all workitems(emberrasingly parallel data/algorithm) to harness the power posessed by gpu.

Best way I know to get rid of simplest branch-vs-compute case is, using a global yes-no array. 0=yes, 1=no : always compute, then multiply your result with the yes-no element of work-item. Generally adding 1-byte element memory-access per core is much better then doing one branching per core. Actually making object length a power of 2 could be better after adding this 1-byte.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. The following elaborations are based on documentation from NVIDIA, but I would doubt it to be any different on ATI hardware (though the actual numbers might differ maybe). In general the threads of a work group are executed in so-called warps, being sub-blocks of the work group size. On NVIDIA hardware each work group is divided into warps of 32 threads each. And each of those warps are executed in lock-step and thus perfectly in parallel (it may not be real-time parallel, meaning there could be 16 threads in parallel and then 16 again directly afterwards, but conceptually they're running perfectly parallel). So if only one of those 32 threads executes that additional code, the others will wait for it. But the threads in all the other warps won't care for all this.

So yes, there may be threads that will unneccessarily wait for the others, but that happens on a smaller scale than the whole work group size (32 on any NVIDIA hardware). This is why intra-warp branch deviation should be avoided if possible and this is also why code that is guaranteed to work inside a single warp only doesn't need any synchronization for e.g. shared memory access (a common optimization for algorithms).